# Build a progressive web apps using angular4.

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I want to build a progressive web app using angular4. I have built some small angular web apps before but never a PWA. While researching I came across many ways to built PWA. Some say that use

1. Ionic Framework to build PWA's
2. PWA using angular4, service workers and manifest.

Can some expert give an advice at this point of time in technology which is the best and scalable solution to build a PWA out of the 2 solutions, Or if you have any other solution that would also be welcome but the only point is that I want to use angular4

Comment: For a real scaling production app, PWAs are just not ready. There is no usable iOS support and even on android devices i don't see how you would go with it. Yes, it's fun to have a shortcut to your webapp on android homescreen, but that's basically it. Go with a hybrid solution for the moment (like Ionic) that you actually end up with an installable product which feels native. Everything else isn't really better then a responsive website imho.

Comment: The problem is we are also developing an android/iOS app for the same. But it is a long way to go. In the meanwhile we want to develop a PWA to quickly showcase our solution/product and also for people hung up on not downloading an app but accessing it directly from the browser. We think we can come up with a PWA faster and with existing technologies like HTML/JS/CSS

Comment: I can relate. I am / was in a similar situation. We have no time, not enough work force, but we need to serve our target group with a mobile friendly app which should have all the power our web app has. I basically had to decide the same thing and i did box through the idea to just take the core of our angular app and build a mobile version in form of a PWA. Huge mistake i can tell you that ;)

Comment: Reasons are...your PWA will not be in any store any time soon, and if, definitely not the apple store. So you dont want to serve only android users, right? The next thing, as soon as you tell your bosses you building a fancy PWA (like i did) they expect something more then a mobile responsive website. but it just isn't. You don't even have a way to force viewport orientation. Go with responsive optimized app until you have a real app going. At least with ionic or maybe xamarin or sth like that if you don't have the time for (two) real native apps.

Comment: I think your experiences are very valuable to me.

Comment: Glad i can help. One more point i want to add. Of course, web workers (even though angular team started to take LESS care of it (just looking at recent Renderer2 changes)) are nice to have for caching stuff and make the loadup process smoother and the way a manifest.json can upgrade your app on mobile chrome a bit is nice too. But these you can add to any website anyway with less effort. doesn't hurt. i just wouldn't call it an alternative to a native app. So your choices should be a) mobile oriented webpage (which you can upgrade a bit with service worker and manifest) or b) a hybrid app.

Comment: Yes nothing can be compared to a native app. Its just while development over the native platforms goes on parallely, we have to come up with something tangible to show quickly(start-up, you know how that goes). we may not develop the PWA with all the features, just that tomorrow if someone asks me show us our product then I have nothing to show!!!. I think at this point I already made my decision to go with angular + service  worker, because we will have to invest some amount of time learning ionic !!

Comment: I understand you. All i say is that if you go with a "pwa" don't try to see it as an app alternative. As i said, its just a mobile oriented webpage. Nothing more. If thats enough (i would say in most cases it is) just to showcase the core of your product, then go with it. Build a service worker to cache your shell, add manifest to provide some users a nice splashscreen and a homescreen button and get rid of the address bar and go for it. If you want more, you need a bit more time and go with ionic. The latter is way more solid of course but still feels crappy for power users who want native.

Answer (score 2):

According this page https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/ on Google Developers

> Progressive Web Apps are user experiences that have the reach of the
> web, and are:
>
> Reliable - Load instantly and never show the downasaur, even in uncertain network conditions.
>
> Fast - Respond quickly to user interactions with silky smooth animations and no janky scrolling.
>
> Engaging - Feel like a natural app on the device, with an immersive
> user experience.

Now, Reliable And Engaging can be developed using `Angular 4` + `Angular 2/4 Material` + `Teradata Covalent`

Angular 4 project has already gained maturity, and Material and Covalent are coming out of Beta, and there are little chances of breaking APIs.

Angular 4 Material: - https://material.angular.io
Teradata Covalent:- https://teradata.github.io/covalent/

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ravinder Payal